# Class Serialization in Java: compatibility after changing field name or getter/setter name

Tags: java, serialization

Suppose we have a Serializable class in Java and we change the name (only the name) of a member of the class and/or its getter or setter, can it cause compatibility errors?

Comment: Yes it can. How is the serializer to know it's the same as something else? Names and types are all it has.

Comment: If you mark the member transient whose name you have changed, there should be no compatibility error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming a field is equivalent to deleting which falls under the section [Incompatible Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a6678) in the specifications.

> 5.6.1 Incompatible Changes
> Incompatible changes to classes are those changes for which the guarantee of interoperability cannot be maintained. The incompatible changes that may occur while evolving a class are:

> Deleting fields - If a field is deleted in a class, the stream written will not contain its value. When the stream is read by an earlier class, the value of the field will be set to the default value because no value is available in the stream. However, this default value may adversely impair the ability of the earlier version to fulfill its contract.