# Java serialization incompatible changes General August 3, 2023

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I 'm trying to use Redis to store HTTP sessions for load balancing. The idea is to be able to deploy with zero downtime, for that I need to store the session in Redis so that users won't lose their session when they go from a server to another.

To do this, I need to make every class in the session serializable. I've been reading about serialization and found out that there are some incompatible changes (source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a6678).

During my tests, I deleted a field from a class and surprisingly didn't run into any issues with serialization. But, I'm not entirely sure if my test is foolproof.

So now, I'm wondering if there's a way or some strategy to make those incompatible changes work properly and if this is necessary.

Comment: it seems to be an incompatible chabge: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a6678 However, this is different if you have writeObject/readObject methods. Also note that you first need to serialize it, then do tze change and then deserialize it in order to run into issues.

Comment: Can you show how you tested it? You might also want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357483/10871900

Comment: It is an incompatible change in that 'the guarantee of interoperability cannot be maintained' in terms of the application. However in terms of the Object Serialization Protocol it will not cause a `SerializationException` as long as you preserve the initial `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: There are two types of incompatibility: backwards incompatibility means that the new version of the code fails to deserialise data saved by the old version. This is almost always important to solve. Forward incompatibility means that the _old_ version of the code fails to deserialise data saved by the _new_ version. This isn't a problem for all applications, but it is in this case. When doing a zero-downtime deployment, there will be a period of time when old and new versions are both running side by side.

Comment: It's possible in that case for the new version to save a session that then needs to be read by another server in the load balancer running the old version of the code. If the deployment rolls through all servers quickly enough, this might be unlikely, but still possible. If you have any kind of pause during the deployment process, it might not be unlikely at all.

Comment: Solving it requires deploying in two stages. In the first stage, you need to deploy a version of the code that still has the field, but can tolerate it being missing without causing any problems. Once all of the servers are running that version of the code, you can deploy a version that removes the field.

Comment: @TimMoore It is *not* a problem in this case. Adding or deleting a field is benign from the serialization point of view. If the field isn't present in the stream but it is in the class, it is set to null, and if it is present in the stream but not in the class it is ignored.

Comment: @user207421 did you read the link in the question? “When the stream is read by an earlier class, the value of the field will be set to the default value because no value is available in the stream. However, this default value may adversely impair the ability of the earlier version to fulfill its contract.” So it depends on how the class actually uses the field. It might assume that it’s not null because it was a required constructor parameter.

Comment: We haven’t seen the class, so we don’t know if that’s the case here. My earlier comment just meant that forward compatibility in general is important for zero-downtime deployments.

Comment: @TimMoore in my case the most likely situation is new version of the code reading old serialized version. We use sticky sessions so, when we do a deployment, the balancer moves users to a another server (with old code) and after the deployment the users go back to the previous server. So in this case new code has old version of the session.

Comment: @TimMoore also, one of my doubts is, in this case, is java going to throw an incompatible class error?

Comment: No, I don’t think it will throw an incompatible class error. At least, that’s what the answer to the question linked as a duplicate says.

Comment: @TimMoore I've addressed that already, and I first read the words you mention in 1997. The change is stream-compatible but *possibly* not application-compatible. We don't know that. You don't know that. You're not in a position to say it is a problem in this case.